Practical example of differences between associativity and alternativity (and the in-between Bol loop)?
Associativity is:
$$(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)$$
Alternativity is:
$$a * (a * b) = (a * a) * b$$
$$(a * b) * b = a * (b * b)$$
Bol loop is:
$${\displaystyle a(b(ac))=(a(ba))c}$$
$${\displaystyle ((ca)b)a=c((ab)a)}$$
The only difference I see between alternativity and associativity is that alternativity is associativity where you only have 2 elements in a combination of 3, while associativity is 3 elements in a combination of 3. Hence alternativity is a "weak" form of associativity. I am still working on understanding the bol loop.
ChatGPT says that octonions (a type of hypercomplex number) is has the alternativity property. But what does this even mean??? What is a practical example, with some calculations, to demonstrate how this looks or when it arises? When does this arise other than in octonions?
I found this by reading about the Bol loop, which seems to be in between alternativity and associativity , how is that even possible?
I am reading about the Bol loop to understand gyrovector spaces, to ultimately understand how to do 2D and 3D renderings of hyperbolic tessellations! Long ways to go haha.

(-1) for ChatGPT.

ChatGPT generally does not "know" anything or "think" in any meaningful way. At best, it synthesizes text to look human-written & predicts what the desired words should be; it does not do real calculations (more). It should not be used for math, as it will get basics wrong or "hallucinate" fake facts. Some extra examples: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

Hi @Lance, it seems you are just experiencing Bol loops as examples of algebras which are alternative but not associative.  Associative algebras are all alternative, so finding such examples is the only way to distinguish associativity from alternativity.  While I can appreciate you may find the situation extraordinary, it does not seem very unusual considering all hierarchical concepts are distinguished this way.  That being the case, it does not seem like there's any question in the post... Is there something concrete to answer?


ChatGPT says that octonions (a type of hypercomplex number) is has the alternativity property.

First of all, please be cautious with chatgpt output about mathematics. It will make all sorts of basic errors (not long ago, it told me the opposite ring of the quaternions is commutative.)

But what does this even mean???

It means those two alternativity identities are satisfied for any choice of $a,b$. What else do you want?

What is a practical example, with some calculations, to demonstrate how this looks or when it arises?

I'm not sure what you expect people to say in a case like this. Why don't you just take two interesting elements of the octionions and compute the results of the above two identities?

When does this arise other than in octonions?

Quaternion algebras, associative algebras, and octonion algebras over other fields than $\mathbb R$ are referenced in the wiki article. Otherwise, it seems like a pretty broad question.

I found this by reading about the Bol loop, which seems to be in between alternativity and associativity , how is that even possible?

It's alternative, but not associative. What is surprising? Is it surprising there are rectangles that aren't squares, for example?
